# How to select part records from the table?

Tags: dolphindb

How to select part records from the table?

I want to select the data between the 50th records and 100th records. Is there a method like "select * from table limit 50,100" in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following statement to query data from row 50 to row 100:

```py
select top 50:100 * from table
```

and use the following statement to query the top 100 row data"

```py
select top 100 * from table
```